# How can i make Pdf from UIImage?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimage

I have one UIImage in my UIViewController and I want to migrate that image to PDF formate so is it possible to such kind of migration?Please guide me i don't have idea of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have UIImageView into UIViewController then call this method:

```
-(NSData*)makePDFfromView:(UIView*)view
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, view.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

Use like this:

```
NSData *pdfData = [self makePDFfromView:imgView];
//[pdfData writeToFile:@"myPdf.pdf" atomically:YES]; - save it to a file
```

Answer (score 9):

It's not very hard, but there are a few steps to set everything up. Basically, you need to create a PDF graphics context, and then draw into it with standard drawing commands. To simply put an UIImage into a PDF, you could do something like the following:

```
// assume this exists and is in some writable place, like Documents
NSString* pdfFilename = /* some pathname */

// Create the PDF context
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFilename, CGRectZero, nil); // default page size
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectZero, nil);

// Draw the UIImage -- I think PDF contexts are flipped, so you may have to
// set a transform -- see the documentation link below if your image draws
// upside down
[theImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

// Ending the context will automatically save the PDF file to the filename
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

For more information, see the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1).